# Is there a way to create db without add data to it ef code-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I started to use the code-first approach with entity framework, When I launch my console app I saw my new data base created in my sql server databases folder, but it created only when I pushed to the data base some data

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new MainModel();

            Product prod = new Product() { ProductName = "milk", ProductPrice = 4 };

            db.Products.Add(prod);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("done!");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Now when I didn`t add any data the database not create.
Is there a way to initial db with code-first approach without pushing data into it?

Comment: please follow one of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341609/entity-framework-code-first-seed-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Code First Seed database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341609/entity-framework-code-first-seed-database)

Comment: If you are using Entity you can build database first in Server using the Explorer manually.   The once the database is built you can use VS to create classes from the existing database.

Comment: None of the above (seeding is exactly was OP doesn't want and it's not database-first) It's enough to just do a _query_ on `db.Products`, for example  `db.Products.Any()`. EF will create the database when any db interaction is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open cmd

2) Go to project folder (by **cd .../yourfolder**)

3) Type **dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration**

4) Then type **dotnet ef database update**

for more details, you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0):

You should create dbContext class:

```
{
    public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```